# JavaScript issue when programmatically adding a partial view to a view in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm following a tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/comments-system-with-asp-net-mvc-5-and-jquery2/

I have an MVC 5 app that has a main view that loads the 1st partial view when the Comment button is clicked OR a new comment is added. The JavaScript ajax calls the action method that returns that 1st partial view and then dynamically builds that 1st partial view area. Now this 1st partial view has a "Reply to Comment" link that when clicked, the JavaScript ajax calls the action method that returns another partial view - the 2nd. The problem is the JavaScript runs the first time - in the main view (Comment button clicked or Add comment button clicked) but NOT the when the link "Reply To Comment" in the 1st partial view area is clicked.

Why?

The area where the "Reply to Comment" link is, is the 1st partial view that was loaded after I added a comment responding to the post.

[image]

For a simple test, I just have an alert in the JavaScript .ready function of the 1st partial view. Nothing else (normally it would have the ajax call for to load the 2nd partial view). However, it does NOT fire off.

Here is the main view that does the JavaScript ajax call to load the 1st partial view. It works fine. It dynamically builds and shows the html area to hold the 1st partial view.

```html
@model IQueryable<Comments.ViewModels.PostsVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetPosts";
}

@if (Model != null)
{
    // Loop threw the model to display the posts.
    foreach (var post in Model)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 80%;">
            @* Panel area. *@
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="~/Images/avatar.png" class="img-circle" style="width: 60px;" />
                    @* Defaulting to a user to start the posts off. *@
                    <span> <a href="" style="font-weight:bold">Danny</a> </span><br />
                    <p style="margin-left: 60px; margin-top: -19px;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <time class="timeago" datetime="@post.PostedDate">@post.PostedDate</time>
                    </p>
                </div>

                @* Post message area. *@
                <div class="postMessage" style="margin-top: 11px; margin-left: 9px;">
                    <span class="label label-warning"> @string.Format("Post #{0}", post.PostID) </span><br />
                    <p class="message">
                        @post.Message
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            @* Panel area - to hold all the comment button. *@
            <div class="panel-footer">
                @* Button. *@
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default Comment" data-id="@post.PostID" value="Comment">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span> Comment
                </button>
            </div>

            @* The area dynamically built. It will hold the partial view - Shared/_MyComments.cshtml. *@

            @* Add comment area. *@
            <div id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}","commentsBlock", post.PostID)" style="border: 1px solid #f1eaea; background-color: #eaf2ff;">
                <div class="AddComment" style="margin-left: 30%;  margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 8px;">
                    <input type="text" id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}", "comment", post.PostID)" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a Comment ..." style="display: inline;" />
                    @* Button. *@
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addComment" data-id="@post.PostID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

<!-- Internal JavaScript. -->
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // For when clicking the Comment button.
            $('.Comment').on('click', function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

                var allCommentsArea = $('<div>').addClass('allComments_' + id);

                // Call the Comments controllers action method to get all the comments related to the post id. Will show a partial view.
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetComments", "Comments")',
                    data: { postId: id },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if ($('div').hasClass('allComments_' + id + ''))
                        {
                            // Remove.
                            $('div[class=allComments_' + id + ']').remove();
                        }

                        // For testing:
                        //console.log(response);

                        // Dynamically building the HTML to hold the comments returned. The area for the Shared/_MyComments.cshtml to be placed.
                        allCommentsArea.html(response);
                        allCommentsArea.prependTo('#commentsBlock_' + id);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to GetComments! Status: " + xhr.status + ". Error: " + thrownError.toString() + ". Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                })
            });

            // For when clicking the addComment button. Adding a new comment.
            $('.addComment').on('click', function () {
                var postId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                var commentMsg = $('#comment_' + postId).val();
                var dateTimeNow = new Date();

                // An object.
                var comment = {
                    CommentMsg: commentMsg,
                    CommentedDate: dateTimeNow.toLocaleString()
                };

                // Call the Comments controllers action method to get add a comment related to the post id. Will show a partial view.
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("AddComment", "Comments")',
                    data: { comment, postId },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('div[class=allComments_' + postId + ']').remove();

                        // Dynamically building the HTML to hold the comments returned which now includes the added comment.
                        // The area for the Shared/_MyComments.cshtml to be placed.
                        var allCommentsArea = $('<div>').addClass('allComments_' + postId);

                        allCommentsArea.html(response);
                        allCommentsArea.prependTo('#commentsBlock_' + postId);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to AddComment! Status: " + xhr.status + ". Error: " + thrownError.toString() + ". Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });

            jQuery("time.timeago").timeago();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Here's the 1st partial view whose JavaScript does not fire off:

```html
@* A partial view called from the GetPosts.cshtml JavaScript function. *@
@* Has Internal Javascript.                                             *@

@* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- *@
@* The @model - in this case the viewModel, contains the data needed here.      *@
@* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- *@

@model IQueryable<Comments.ViewModels.CommentsVM>

@using Comments.ViewModels;

@if (Model != null)
{ 
    @* Loop threw the model to display the comments. *@
    foreach (CommentsVM comment in Model)
    {
        // A row.
        <div class="row" style="width: 100.3%; border-bottom: 1px solid #d2cece; margin-right: -14px; margin-left: -1px;">
            @* A column. *@
            <div class="col-md-4" style="width: 21%;">
                <div class="userProfil" style="margin-left: 9px; margin-top: 12px;">
                    <img src="~/Images/@comment.Users.ImageProfile" class="img-circle" style="width: 46px; height: 53px; border: 1px solid #bcb8b8;" />
                    <a href="#" style="margin-left: 5px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;"> @comment.Users.UserName </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            @* A column. *@
            <div class="col-md-7" style="width: 60%;">
                <div class="commentDetails">
                    @* Area to hold the comment. *@
                    <p style="margin-top: 27px; font-size: 13px; color: #9c9898;"> @comment.CommentMsg </p>

                    <a href="#" class="Reply" data-id="@comment.CommentID">Reply To Comment</a>

                    <div class="@string.Format("{0}_{1}", "ReplayComments", comment.CommentID)" style="display:none;">
                        @* Area to add a sub comment. *@
                        <div class="ReplayCommentInput" style="margin-left: 3%;  margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 8px;">
                            <input type="text" id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}", "inputReplay", comment.CommentID)" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a Comment ..." style="display: inline;" />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ReplyAddComment" data-id="@comment.CommentID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            @* A column. *@
            <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 19%;">
                <div class="commentDate">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <time class="timeago" style="margin-top: 27px; font-size: 13px; color: #9c9898;  margin-left: 4px;" datetime="@comment.CommentedDate">@comment.CommentedDate</time>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        // For testing:
        alert("here I am");
     });
</script>
```

Now when the "Reply to Comment" link is clicked in the 1st partial, it is to fire off a JavaScript ajax call to load the 2nd partial view - I have it to  just firing off an alert for now. This is when the JavaScript does NOT fire off at all.

Comment: for the second partial view try move the script block out of `@section Scripts`. If the page you are referring a truly `partial view` sections are not respected

Comment: I did that originally..but tried it again. I removed it. No change.

Comment: Ok. I quickly scanned your markup (of the first view) and it appears there are two elements with the same class name `addComment` and `AddComment` - those might collide and won't trigger the right event.

Comment: The Add comment button clicked works fine. It is what I did to add the comment and then display the 1st partial view. It now in this 1st partial view that its "Reply to Comment" link is clicked and the JavaScript does not fire off to show my alert.

Comment: Sometimes javascript errors prevent other parts of the script from not working. Any chance to see the browser's console window if it's free of errors?

Comment: @mike123 Sure enough, there is an Uncaught TypeError: JQuery(...) timeag0 is not a function. At the bottom of the main view there is this: jQuery("time.timeago").timeago(); This is the Authors and not sure what that is. I commented out and now the JavaScript fires off to return the 2nd partial view.

Comment: @mike123...how do i give you credit?

Comment: It's all good. Glad you had it sorted it out :)